# Small scale integration single board computer?

Tags: motherboard

This Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_System_Development_Kit) mentions about Intel SDKs; single board computers that contained Intel microprocessors.

I would like to own one of those SDKs but I doubt that they are still in production. So, I am looking for something similar to Intel SDKs. The kit must:

- Feature a microprocessor. Not a microcontroller.
- Preferably contains an x86 microprocessor. But this is not a must.
- The less integrated functionality, the better. (I.e, it is better to have discrete components for various functionality than to have a single component that does everything)

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about the [Edison](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PTVSS4A). It is an Intel SBC with most functionality offloaded to breakout boards connecting to the Edison via a bus on its underside. Has a dual core 500mhz Atom processor by Intel onboard which is x86.

AFAIK they are still in production. The breakout board will probably cost you more than the SBC, though.